# Force Box.com access token to expire

Tags: box-api

I am trying to develop a "never expiring" connection between my web app and Box.com API.
I am refreshing the access_token (which lasts for 1h) with the refresh_token (which lasts for 14d) with cron job every 50 min. It works so far, but I want to make the cron job to execute every ... 10/13 days. Currently I cannot refresh the access_token when it's expired.

I am trying to fix the refresh token bug, but my bigger problem is that I have to wait one hour for access_token to expire so I can test my changes and here is my question...

(How) can I manually force expiration of the access_token (only).

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh an access token at any time.  You don't have to wait for (or force) it to expire.  The refresh token changes along with the access token, so be sure to save both.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to run the cron every 50 min (less than 1h). I want to run it every 13 days, but I have a bug in this code so I need a way to force the access_token to be expired (like 1h passed already since the last refresh).

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need the access token to be expired.  Can you say more about why this is necessary?

Comment: For debug purposes only in development environment. I want to debug my script for refreshing the access_token with the refresh_token when the access_token is already expired.

Comment: For the purposes of refreshing an access token, it simply does not matter if the access token is expired. The refresh token should work the same way in either case.

Comment: Well it seems the problem was in another part of the code. I thought this is the case. Anyway. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to revoke a token, there's documentation on that:  http://developers.box.com/docs/#oauth-2-revoke

But that revokes both the auth token, and the refresh token.  They are treated as a joined pair, and revoking them lets you tell Box to kill the paired set.